# acceder a una tabla LUA

Tags: lua

estoy estudiando las tablas en lua
he visto tablas asi que no comprendo bien esta la copie de algun lado y quiero comprenderlo y imprimirlo con print() pero solo pude hacerlo con 2

```
    variable = {'val1',{tab= '123'},{tabb= {{tabbb= '456'},
{kkk= '456'}
  }}
}
print(variable[1]) -- result val1
print(variable[2].tab) -- result 123
```

como imprimir correctamente estos valores con print() sin usar for ?

Comment: Lua no soporta la impresión de tablas completas sin usar `for`.

Comment: como lo haria usted para imprimir estas tablas completas con for ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te comparto un script que uso para imprimir todo el contenido de las tablas de forma recursiva.

```
function print_r ( t )
    local print_r_cache={}
    local function sub_print_r(t,indent)
        if (print_r_cache[tostring(t)]) then
            print(indent.."*"..tostring(t))
        else
            print_r_cache[tostring(t)]=true
            if (type(t)=="table") then
                for pos,val in pairs(t) do
                    if (type(val)=="table") then
                        print(indent.."["..pos.."] => "..tostring(t).." {")
                        sub_print_r(val,indent..string.rep(" ",string.len(pos)+8))
                        print(indent..string.rep(" ",string.len(pos)+6).."}")
                    elseif (type(val)=="string") then
                        print(indent.."["..pos..'] => "'..val..'"')
                    else
                        print(indent.."["..pos.."] => "..tostring(val))
                    end
                end
            else
                print(indent..tostring(t))
            end
        end
    end
    if (type(t)=="table") then
        print(tostring(t).." {")
        sub_print_r(t,"  ")
        print("}")
    else
        sub_print_r(t,"  ")
    end
    print()
end
```

solo copia, pega y usala.
El script no es mío.